# How to slideOutVertically very slowly in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetpack-compose-animation, android-jetpack-compose-animation

I want to slide out vertically from my initial position to another point very slowly. Suppose my initial position is `50.dp` THEN it goes to `49.dp`,`48.dp`....`0.dp`. I tried some piece of code but to goes to directly 0.dp and then hide which i don't want. Can you guys help me on this.

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalAnimationApi::class)
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun MoveText() {
    var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    var yPosition by remember {
        mutableStateOf(50.dp)
    }
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = visible) {
        yPosition = if (visible) {
            50.dp
        } else {
            0.dp
        }
    }
    ScrollComposeTheme {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
        ) {
            AnimatedVisibility(
                visible = visible,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(top = yPosition),
                exit = slideOutVertically(
                    animationSpec = tween(4000),
                )
            ) {
                val color by transition.animateColor(label = "color") { state ->
                    if (state == EnterExitState.Visible) Color.Black else Color.Gray
                }
                Column {
                    Icon(
                        imageVector = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart,
                        tint = color,
                        contentDescription = null,
                    )
                    Text(
                        text = "Hello, Anna",
                        fontSize = 20.sp,
                        color = color,
                    )
                }
            }
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .absoluteOffset(y = 10.dp),
                onClick = {
                    visible = !visible
                },
            ) {
                Text(text = "Move Text")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After research I got to use `animateDpAsState` and which is fixed my problem. I am adding a code in here

```
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun MoveText() {
    var visible by remember { mutableStateOf(true) }
    val iconOffsetAnimation: Dp by animateDpAsState(
        if (visible) 13.dp else 0.dp,
        tween(1000)
    )
    val textOffsetAnimation: Dp by animateDpAsState(
        if (visible) 19.dp else 5.dp,
        tween(1000)
    )
    ScrollComposeTheme {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(start = 16.dp, top = 16.dp)
        ) {
            Column {
                Icon(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .absoluteOffset(y = iconOffsetAnimation),
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.ShoppingCart,
                    tint = Color.Black,
                    contentDescription = null,
                )
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .absoluteOffset(y = textOffsetAnimation),
                    text = "Hello, Anna",
                    fontSize = 20.sp,
                    color = Color.Black,
                )
            }
            Button(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .absoluteOffset(y = 30.dp),
                onClick = {
                    visible = !visible
                },
            ) {
                Text(text = "Move Text")
            }
        }
    }
}
```